How to jointly derive the FIM for angle and range?
The received echo signal at the radar receiver can be given as follows,
$$y=\alpha \textbf{b}(\theta)\textbf{a}^T(\theta)s(t-\tau)+n,$$
where $\alpha$ is the amplitude related to the target's RCS and so on, $\textbf{a}(\theta)$ and $\textbf{b}(\theta)$ are the transmit and receive steering vector of the radar, respectively. $\tau$ is the transmit delay.
It should first go through matched filtering for range estimation and interference cancellation (e.g. the bistatic interference, meaning the signals transmitted from other radars), and then use the output of the matched filtering for range estimation.
If I want to derive the CRB for the range estimation and angle estimation, I can only derive them one by one? I mean, to derive the range estimation CRB using the received signal before matched filtering, and then derive the angle CRB using the output from the matched filter? Is there a way to derive them jointly? And the output of the matched filter seems to be deprived of the delay (range) information that used to lie in $s(t−τ)$
... I am quite confused.

What is it exactly that you're trying to accomplish? Are you really trying to calculate the proper Fisher information matrix to perform detection and/or tracking? Or are you maybe a bit confused (by some material that you read or heard) about how to accomplish range/angle estimation for detection and tracking?

I am trying to derive the Fisher information matrix for range and angle estimation. @Envidia

You should look into the Slepian-Bangs formula. The FIM will be a block diagonal matrix.

"And the output of the matched filter seems to be deprived of the delay (range) information that used to lie in s(t−τ) ... I am quite confused." You seem to be both confused on some fundamental aspects and also trying to derive a fairly advanced characterization of a collection scenario. I would take a step back and do some self-study on the basics and then come back and ask good, targeted questions that are answerable.
